# How to use Revoke in express jwt to only allow admins to post

Tags: node.js, express, express-jwt

I have a series of apis that i'm trying to protect by using isRevoked from expressJWT. I'm allowing the GET requests on certain routes but I need to prevent regular users from Posting. I tried several codes using isRevoked but none of them is working.

In Postman I first login in to get the token then use it for posting but I'm being returned an empty Json with a 500 internal server error with no message so I guess I am doing something wrong.
How could I make it work ?

```
const { expressjwt: expressJwt } = require("express-jwt");

function authJwt() {
  const secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET;
  const api = process.env.API_URL;
  return expressJwt({
    secret: secret,
    algorithms: ["HS256"],
    isRevoked: isRevoked,
  }).unless({
    path: [
      { url: /\/api\/v1\/products(.*)/, methods: ["GET", "OPTIONS"] },
      { url: /\/api\/v1\/categories(.*)/, methods: ["GET", "OPTIONS"] },
      `${api}/users/login`,
      `${api}/users/register`,
      `${api}/users/reset-password`,
    ],
  });
}

async function isRevoked(req, token) {
  console.log("Token : ", token);
  if (!token.payload.isAdmin) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: You should problem return false in `isRevoked` if the payload isn't an admin.

Answer (score 0):

this work for me

```js
async function isRevok(req, token) {
    if (token.payload.isAdmin===false) {
        return  true
    }  return false

}
```